# Nested for in windows batch (*.bat) file

Tags: android, windows, batch-file

I need to implement script that in loop executes command and inline iteration varible there in 2 digit format. I can't understand how to properly work with variables in batch file. What I'm doing wrong?

```
for /l %%h in (0,1,23) do (
SET padded_h1=0%%h
SET padded_h=%padded_h1:~-2%

for /l %%m in (0,1,59) do (
    SET padded_min1=0%m%
    SET padded_min=%padded_min1:~-2%

    C:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb -e shell date -s 20131202.%padded_h%%padded_min%00 
    ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 > nul
)
```

)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic rule with variables in batch files is: each line, or each block if there is one, is parsed and variables replaced with values **when readed**, unless explicitly asked for delayed substitution.

That means that a `for` block with varibles inside (except the %% variables of the command) get all variables replaced with values when it is reached, and in each loop there are no variables, just its values.

Except if delayed expansion is enabled and variables are referenced as !var! instead of %var%

So, with the variables replaced with its valued when the block is read,  as is, your code is executed by cmd as it is has been written

```
for /l %%h in (0,1,23) do (
    SET padded_h1=0%%h
    SET padded_h=

    for /l %%m in (0,1,59) do (
        SET padded_min1=0%m%
        SET padded_min=

        C:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb -e shell date -s 20131202.00 
        ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 > nul
    )
)
```

As the variables have no initial value, when for block (from start to end parenthesis) is read, and variables replaced with their values, you get this.

So, your code should look as

```
rem Enable delayed expansion
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

for /l %%h in (0,1,23) do (
    rem %%h is a for variable, no problems with it
    SET padded_h1=0%%h

    rem padded_h1 has changed its value inside de for, so 
    rem we need to get the changed value not the initial value
    rem the variable had when the block was readed
    SET padded_h=!padded_h1:~-2!

    rem and the same with the inner loop    
    for /l %%m in (0,1,59) do (
        SET padded_min1=0%%m
        SET padded_min=!padded_min1:~-2!

        C:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb -e shell date -s 20131202.!padded_h!!padded_min!00 
        ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 > nul
    )

)
```

Comment: In your paste bin `for /L %h in (0 1 23) do (` in my code `for /l %%h in (0,1,23) do (`

Comment: I don't know why this happens but it's 100% of your code. Please look here: http://s020.radikal.ru/i722/1311/f9/b2c25a7c85f3.png

Comment: I see. But also i see it is working. Add `@echo off` as the first line in your bat to hide command parsing and prefix your adb call with `echo c:\android...` so it shows in screen what is intended to run. BUT all this does not ensure your adb command is correct, just the variables in batch are working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use variables set within a for loop inside of the loop without DelayedExpansion.

Change it to this:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /l %%h in (0,1,23) do (
    SET padded_h1=0%%h
    SET padded_h=!padded_h1:~-2!

    for /l %%m in (0,1,59) do (
        SET padded_min1=0%m%
        SET padded_min=!padded_min1:~-2!

        C:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb -e shell date -s 20131202.!padded_h!!padded_min!00 
        ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 > nul
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I have strange result in console: http://pastebin.com/EnFUNHcb