# For loop in Windows batch file: Error: "The syntax of the command is incorrect"

Tags: batch-file, syntax, command

this is a follow-up to my question asked in this thread: 
[Extracting string after last instance of delimiter in a Batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20004597/extracting-string-after-last-instance-of-delimiter-in-a-batch-file)

I am working on writing a batch file that takes an unknown number of strings denoting directories from a java program (which calls the .bat) as arguments. These directories are saved in an "array" called "dirs".

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%z in ('set dirs[') do (
    set "parm=%~1"
    for %%a in (%parm:\= %) do set folder=%%a
    echo %folder%
    shift
)
```

The "dirs" array will hold on to the actual directory without changing it in any way, and eventually I will be using it with xcopy as the directory to be copied from. Parm takes the actual parameters put into the batch file and manipulates it to extract the last part of the directory. A variable called "folder" stores this directory name and prints it to the command line. However, when I run the program I constantly get an error saying "The syntax of the command is incorrect". I tried narrowing down where exactly the problem was, and it's definitely within the above loop. In order for the outer loop to work, does the %%z have to be operated on in some way? The loop works when I replace its contents with a simple "echo %%z", so it made me wonder if that's where the issue lies.

EDIT: Here is the updated loop, with the xcopy line included:

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%z in ('set dirs[') do (
set "param=%~1"
set param=!param:\= !
for %%a in (!param!) do set lastDir=%%a
    echo !lastDir!
XCOPY %%z\*.* !outdrive!:\!dir!\!lastDir! /C /S /D /Y /I
shift
)
```

In case you need to know, "outdrive" is an external hard drive, "dir" is the backup directory created earlier in the program, and lastDir should be self-explanatory. It's the folder name, i.e. "pictures" or "documents"

**Final Edit:**

Thank you all who replied. I am kicking myself for not seeing the answer before, but I have figured out some code that works as expected. Here is the loop as it currently sits, operating properly:

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%z in ('set dirs[') do (
    set param=%%z
    set param=!param:\= !
    for %%a in (!param!) do set lastDir=%%a
    XCOPY %%z\*.* !outdrive!:\!dir!\!lastDir! /C /S /D /Y /I
)
```

Instead of using the parameters that were passed in to the batch file, I am working directly from the "dirs" array. I am then setting a different variable to the specified directory string, and operating upon that variable, rather than the string stored in the array.

Comment: Just [answered today](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20001130/2861476). Not the same code but the same problem. Please, adapt as needed.

Comment: And, Why are you iterating over the dirs array and not using the data?. And, if dirs array has been populated from arguments that have been retrieved iterating with shift, then arguments are consumed, no more arguments, so, what value will %1 have?

Comment: I will be using the "dirs" array eventually, I have the loop trimmed down for debugging at this point. "dirs" was not populated by iterating using Shift, I used a slightly more complex system to obtain the values for the "dirs" array without manipulating the batch input parameters. As for the link, I understand what they're saying but I do not see which of my variables is declared outside the loop that is then changed inside. All the variables I use inside the loop were created inside the loop, so I'm a bit confused as to how the code in the link relates.

Comment: You need a line `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` at some time before your first use of the `!var!` construct to activate `delayedexpansion` mode. Directly after the `@echo off` is fine. `SHIFT` has no effect in this case. It shifts the procedure parameters' indices.

Comment: I do have that line at the top of my program. I just got my program to work, I will post the final loop as a second edit in my main post for future readers. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon the updated information, this should display the commands you need, and delayed expansion isn't needed in this code snippet.

```
@echo off
set outdrive=E
set dir=backup

set dirs[1]=c:\folders1
set dirs[2]=c:\folders2
set dirs[3]=c:\folders3
set dirs[4]=c:\folders4

for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%z in ('set dirs[') do (
echo XCOPY "%%z\*.*" "%outdrive%:\%dir%\%%~nxz\" /C /S /D /Y /I
)
pause
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I see only one problem in that, and that is that I do  not know how many directories there are in the "dirs" array, so the first part (set dirs[1]=.....) is a bit difficult. I did find a way to do it, and I'm kicking myself for not seeing it earlier. I am about to add it as an edit to my first post. Thank you very much foxidrive, you've been very helpful pushing me in the right direction!

Comment: The code in my loop does exactly what your final edit does - without using delayed expansion.  `%%~nxz` is the last folder (or filename) in the string. See the help in the last page for **FOR /?**

Comment: Woops, you're absolutely right! That code does work, except for the fact that I keep getting an error in the command window saying it cannot find the drive specified. I can't seem to figure out where it's getting this. I'll do a bit more digging, but either way it's working overall now. Many thanks, and I will accept this as the answer =)

Comment: Hmm, that was strange. I took out some of my code that was commented out and it worked like a charm.... Is it common for the system to try to run commands that have been commented out using ::? Perhaps I should use REM instead?

Comment: When using `::` inside a loop it will cause issues (only in certain lines, like before the last parenthesis) so it's always safer to use REM inside a loop.  I'm glad you got it sorted out.

Answer (score 2):

Use Delayed Expansion and the changed syntax for `!variables!` if you need to use the variables in the loop.

The `shift` command is doing nothing to the loop variables.

Comment: Thank you very much, the "!"s fixed that issue. As for the "shift", you are correct, it's not doing anything. Is there a way to access/shift through the variables within the loop?

Comment: Change the `shift` to `pause` and it will show you each pass when you hit a key.

Comment: This batch file is supposed to run without any user input, so I don't want it to rely on the user monitoring the command line. Right now it simply prints Pictures (the first directory) over and over again and the shift has no effect. I was hoping there was a way I could do the same thing as shift so that I can change the string each iteration of the loop.

Comment: You aren't using delayed expansion correctly in that case.  Add the code you are using at the bottom of your question.

Comment: I just added the current code. And I apologize, I couldn't seem to get the spacing right

Comment: See my other answer.  is that what you need to do?